# How to make event.target property work within the function expression

Tags: javascript

I have list of items and I need to get the class name by clicking on a specific list item. However I cannot access the `event.target` property within the function. I have a function and an eventlistener. Event listeners are within the `eventListnerInit` function, so when I click on a list item I cannot make the `event.target` property to work inside the `deleteitems` function expression.

```js
let fntaskController = (function(taskEvent, UIrender, taskstorage) {
  let eventListnerInit = function() {    
    document.querySelector(taskEvent.dom.deleteEvent).addEventListener('click', deleteItems.bind(this.event));
  }

  let deleteItems = function(ev) {
    //delete list items   
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      //Event Listner Initilization
      eventListnerInit();
    }
  }
})(fninputevnt, fntaskUI, fntaskLocalStorage);

fntaskController.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event callback will automatically include event in its argument, so you shouldn't need to bind anything at all:

```
document.querySelector(taskEvent.dom.deleteEvent).addEventListener('click', deleteItems);
```